# How do i make buttons stay in one place in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok, this problem has been hounding me for about 2 weeks now and with all the research I've done, I still can't figure this out.  I have 6 buttons in the form of a pie chart.  When I do the layout in the XML, I can make them look fine.

[image: view I want to achieve]

When I change it to a tablet size or another size screen all my buttons move and look horrible.

[image: bad view]

How do I make these Buttons stationary across any screen size?  I know that I will have to have different image sizes in the approriate folders and I plan to do that, but I need to know if there is a way to lock these in a certain position in the XML file or what I need to do to make this work properly.  As always any and all help is greatly appreciated and I will answer any questions if I am not clear enough on my question.  THANKS

Here is my XML

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainback" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ipadcollegesm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ipadmusicsm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/ipadfamilysm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/ipadyouthsm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ipadlinkssm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@drawable/ipadpodcastsm" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there you go, forgot to do that and was doing that as you commented.  I have tried to do a frame layout with relative layout nested in it and that just didn't work right either so this is the basic premis on what i want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've provided a fixed dp for each button, different devices have different resolutions.

To make this work on multiple devices with the least amount of work, I'd suggest adding another relative layout as the root, and setting the gravity as center. This way, the layout is always in the center of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/mainback">
   <RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      *** Your buttons would be here ***

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Another way is having a dimens file for each screen size, but above is probably the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: would i change anything on the buttons or just leave them the way i have them and just nest them in the second relative layout

Comment: I would assume that they should be fine, but as the scholar Justin Bieber once said "Never say never". Perhaps adding a FrameLayout or something that holds center, and then using that as an anchor would be more beneficial to you.